# Visual Studio 2010 C# Outlining works improperly

Tags: visual-studio, outlining

So, code blocks (which can be collapsed like #region blocks) have corresponding markers (+ symbols) to the left of the text editor. These markers should be placed right where the code block starts. My problem is that they are shifted upwards a bit.

Here is a screenshot in case I didn't explain the issue clearly enough: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/3489/04071173010.jpg

**upd:** This behavior was caused by an extension (thx Nija). In my case it was Presentation Zoom. However disabling and enabling it again fixed the problem.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have any plugins or extensions installed? I haven't seen this exactly, but have gotten other odd behavior due to an plugin/extension.  (I agree with @Andrew Cooper)

Comment: Definitely not normal.  Can you give any more information about how this reproduces?  i.e. do you have this problem after restarting Visual Studio?  In different C# projects?  In different project types?  Does something in particular trigger the behavior?  Does it get worse after long periods of use?

Comment: Looks to me like it is confuzzled about the font metrics.  Pick another font.

Answer (score 0):

Try deselecting automatic outlining mode by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced and unchecking "Enter outlining mode when files open".

Restart Visual Studio.

If that doesn't work, try installing the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) addon, which add more flexibility to the existing Visual Studio features and may correct your outlining.

If all else fails you might have to do an uninstall / repair.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that often helps me in this situation ... is to **quickly delete all the xmlns namespace definitions and then add them back with undo (Ctrl-Z)**.

I know, odd, but it often works.

Comment: Just to be clear ... in my cases ... outlining doesn't show up at all ... it's like it isn't turned on.